# Como eu faço um switch de classes de botões que acionam um player para aparecer e ocultar?

Tags: jquery, classes, switch, click, addclass

Eu tenho 3 botões no formato de Link  com as classes: .icon-play, .icon-pause e .icon-download, eu quero mudar a classe play com pause, assim como o inverso, sem influenciar o botão de download, assim que o icon-play for clicado vai mostrar um player e se o pause for ativado vai ocultar o player.

```
var btnplay = $(".livro-audio a").find(".icon-play");
var btnpause = $(".livro-audio a").find(".icon-pause");

$( btnplay ).click(function() {
 $( '.player-active' ).show();
 $(this).attr('class', 'icon-pause');
 if($('.player-active:visible')){
    $( ".livro-audio" ).last().css( "margin-bottom", "150px" );
    $( ".livro-video" ).last().css( "margin-bottom", "150px" );
  }
});

$( btnpause ).click(function() {
  $( '.player-active' ).hidden();
  $(this).attr('class', 'icon-play');
  if($('.player-active:hidden')){
    $( ".livro-audio" ).last().css( "margin-bottom", "80px" );
    $( ".livro-video" ).last().css( "margin-bottom", "80px" );
  }

});
```

Até o momento o Lucas me deu uma luz, ficando assim:

```
 $(".livro-audio a").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('icon-play')){
   $(this).addClass('icon-pause').removeClass('icon-play');
   $('.player-active').show();
  }
 else{
   $(this).addClass('icon-play').removeClass('icon-pause');
   $('.player-active').hide();
  }
});
```

Só que esse código mexe com o minha terceira classe .icon-download, tem alguma forma de identificá-lo, para ele não receber as classes play e pause quando ele for clicado, obrigada.

Comment: coloca um id no botão play/pause (tipo "btnPlayPause") e muda o seletor do jquery de ``$(".livro-audio a")`` para ``$("#btnPlayPause")``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) e [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) para trocar o estilo no elemento.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("#player").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('player_azul'))
    $(this).addClass('player_ver').removeClass('player_azul');
  else 
    $(this).addClass('player_azul').removeClass('player_ver');
});
```

```css
.player_azul{
  background: blue;
}

.player_ver{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="player">Elemento</div>
```

Este é apenas um exemplo que você pode adaptar ao seu caso. Em algumas situações é interessante usar também o [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) do jQuery.